# Why do some translations render Genesis 3:8 with "the voice of the Lord" while others don't? Is it a reference to Jesus?

Tags: genesis, bible-translation, word-of-god

Genesis 3:8, depending on the translation, says one of two things with regards to what Adam and Eve heard:

1. They heard "the *voice* of the Lord" walking in the garden

or

2. The sound of the Lord God as *he* was walking in the garden.

It seems that in example one, the translations are intending to mean that the actual **voice** of the Lord God was *walking* in the garden, that is, had feet. In the second group, it seems they are stating simply that the Lord could be *heard* walking in the garden. Two very distinct interpretations.

## KJV

> “**And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking** in the garden in
>   the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the
>   presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden.”

## Word English Bible

> **They heard the voice of Yahweh God walking** in the garden in the cool
>   of the day, and the man and his wife hid themselves from the presence
>   of Yahweh God among the trees of the garden.

---

Now, compare that to:

## NIV

> **Then the man and his wife heard the sound of the LORD God** as he was
>   walking in the garden in the cool of the day, and they hid from the
>   LORD God among the trees of the garden.

## ESV

> **And they heard the sound of the LORD God walking** in the garden in the
>   cool of the day, and the man and his wife hid themselves from the
>   presence of the LORD God among the trees of the garden.

---

Is it possible that some translations are referencing the Memra of the Lord (as seen in the Aramaic Targum)? http://juchre.org/articles/word.htm
The Memra is known as the **voice** of the Lord, the glory of the Lord, the Angel of the Lord, etc. [Some, in fact, connect the Memra with Jesus Christ](http://www.lineoffireradio.com/2012/08/16/memra-logos-and-the-divine-messiah/). Jesus, of course, being called the logos or the word of God.

So, are there any traditions, commentaries, church fathers, etc., that hold that, specifically, the individual walking in the garden in Genesis 3:8 was Jesus and not God the Father?

Comment: The KJV and similar translations can be interpreted two ways: [They heard the voice of] [the LORD God walking in the garden] or [They heard the voice of the LORD God] [walking in the garden].

Comment: Judaism supports the KJV/WEB translations.  [See here.](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167)

Comment: you are biblically correct.When they heard the "voice of the Lord" it means the Word is communicated and the Word was God and the Word is the Logos which is Jesus Christ. The Father symbol is WILL, and when the Will is spoken thru Word. The Word is alive & active (Hebrews4:12) and connect it with John3:8 the Light will guide you to complete the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

There is one commentary that I am familiar which does in fact purport that is a reference to the preincarnate Jesus; that is the commentary on the whole Bible by [David Guzik](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Comm/guzik_david/StudyGuide2017-Gen/Gen-3.cfm). I will inset it here that you do not have to look it up.

> And they heard the sound of the Lord God walking in the garden in the cool of the day, and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the Lord God among the trees of the garden. Then the Lord God called to Adam and said to him, "Where are you?"
>
> a. They heard the sound of the Lord God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: Adam and Eve knew that when they heard the Lord coming, He would want to be with them. This was how the Lord had fellowship with Adam and Eve, in a very natural, close, intimate way.
>
> i. Leupold on walking in the garden in the cool of the day: "The almost casual way in which this is remarked indicates that this did not occur for the first time just then . . . There is extreme likelihood that the Almighty assumed some form analogous to the human form which was made in His image."
>
> ii. ***We can assume this is God, in the Person of Jesus Christ***, appearing to Adam and Eve before His incarnation and birth at Bethlehem, because of God the Father it is said, "No one has seen God at any time. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has declared Him" (Joh. 1:18), and no man has ever seen God in the Person of the Father. (1Ti. 6:16)

One of the niceties of Guzik is that he backs up his assertions with Scripture. That of course does not mean that those assertions are true unless you ascribe to the concept that Scripture is the inerrant word of God. Which would necessitate that all Scripture even remotely associated with this assertion be studied in depth, and even then many would not draw the same conclusion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be scripturally sound to ascribe the "Voice" of the Lord as Yahshua walking in the garden! For one Yeshua states that he was in the behind with God she all things were created. Not only this but that all things were created through him Colossians 1:16. Hebrews one declares that Yahshua is the exact, expression and divine glory of the Father! And as other posters have ststed no man has seen God (The Father) at any time save he who has come down from God (The Father). That is the one who is in the bossism of the Father. It also seems fitting for scripture as it states; Yahshua said, "I beheld Satan falling from heaven like lightning!" Satan has fallen before the creation or placement of man, or how could he be in the Garden of Eden possessing the snake! Remember also the Yahshua said; search the scriptures for in them ye think that you have eternal life, but they are that which testify of me! So then all scripture points to Jesus Christ he is the center the focus of all scripture. An exemplary statement in St.John1:1-3 &1:14 is that Jesus is the Word which is with God and was God. That is Jesus existed in the form of God before his incarnation Phillipians 2:6-10. So then we know that the person of Christ is not created but eternally existent. Some may argue that this is metaphorical or poetic soeach, but from a Christeological standing we can see that Yahshua is God's divine Word.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sadly most of what you have written is derived from misunderstood scripture. Jesus was born approx. 4 BC There is no mention of him until this except as the one prophesied to come. Col 1 does not say he created the world or universe - that is a wrong translation. John 1 speaks of the word - not Jesus. If you are interested in what the bible *actually* says on these matters read my other posts. Otherwise, I wish you the best in your learning.

Comment: @steveowen your commentary is considered off-topic here. Most Christians would not accept the premises you outline -- that doesn't mean it can't be discussed here, but it cannot be discussed as though it is right and other interpretations are necessarily wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you’re right, I was a bit *enthusiastic* for the word. There is a clear reading of these things, so should we extend that which ignores the plain words of life?

Comment: @steveowen "There is no mention of him until this except as the one prophesied to come." Counterpoint: John 1.

Comment: @nick - so what is your point exactly? Which part of John1? Ambiguous statements are a great space and time waster - just make your point clearly and succinctly.

Comment: @steveowen "so what is your point exactly?" Jesus existed long before He took on flesh. "Which part of John1?" The entire chapter.

Comment: @nick Thanks, Jesus doesn't begin until he was conceived/born, this is, ' the logos became flesh' v14. All that is said v1-3 is the logos - which is NOT yet Jesus. While this might seem strange, it is simply what we are provided. We should not read in what is not there. As 1 John 1 shows the logos is not a person, but a 'which', the word of God.

Comment: @steveowen So, you're not a trinitarian, then? The Logos/Son is one of the three persons of God, just like the Father and Holy Spirit, according to trinitarian thought.

Comment: Yeah, apparently - but the bible doesn't teach that. Thanks for the chat.